# How do server based notifications work on android?

Tags: android

I have noticed applications like whatsapp which give notifications without the user actually using the app at that time. How does the server send a message notification to the app , without using C2D ?

Comment: There is other library available which are parallel to GCM (in your word C2D), for example http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhatsApp runs permanently as a background service so is always available to receive data from the server:

[image: WhatsApp]